# Semi-Fancy Regex.Replace() function

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Words placed after these punctuation marks must be capitalized (note that there may be spaces or special characters on either side of these when used):

dash ( - ), slash ( / ), colon ( : ), period ( . ), question mark ( ? ), exclamation
point ( ! ), ellipsis (... OR …) (they are different)

I am sort of bogged down on this puzzle because of all of the special regex characters that I am trying to literally look for in my search. I believe I can use Regex.Escape although I cannot get it working for me right now in this case.

A few examples of starting strings to change to might be:

```
Change this:
This is a dash - example
To this:
This is a dash - Example       <--capitalize "Example" with Regex

This is another dash -example
This is another dash -Example

This is an ellipsis ... example
This is an ellipsis ... Example

This is another ellipsis …example
This is another ellipsis …Example

This is a slash / example
This is a slash / Example

This is a question mark ? example
This is a question mark ? Example
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private static string[] postCaps = { "-", "/", ":", "?", "!", "...", "…"};
private static string ReplacePostCaps(string strString)
{

    foreach (string postCap in postCaps)
    {

        strString = Regex.Replace(strString, Regex.Escape(postCap), "/(?<=(" + Regex.Escape(postCap) + "))./", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);   

    }
    return strString;

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: To capitalize, you will need the version of the Regex.Replace() method where it has a replacement callback.

Comment: Spend a few hours going through this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html it's heavy going in places but goes into detail about what the regex engine is actually doing with the pattern.

Comment: Why do you use a regex at all? The task can be done by a simple string.Replace()

Comment: I added my example code. @TomB you may be onto something there. Good point. Can you elaborate? I know what the characters I am looking for are, of course. But I do not know if they are followed by a space or not and I do not know what the word after that will be, but I know I want to capitalize that word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to iterate over a list of punctuation but instead could just add a character set in a single regex:

```
(?:[/:?!…-]|\.\.\.)\s*([a-z])
```

To use it with `Regex.Replace()`:

```
strString = Regex.Replace(
    strString,
    @"(?:[/:?!…-]|\.\.\.)\s*([a-z])",
    m => m.ToString().ToUpper()
);
```

Regex Explained:

```
(?:                 # non-capture set
    [/:?!…-]        # match any of these characters
    | \.\.\.        # *or* match three `.` characters in a row
)
\s*                 # allow any whitespace between matched character and letter
([a-z])             # match, and capture, a single lowercase character
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you:

```
var phrase = "This is another dash ... example";
var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=[\-./:?!]) *\w");
var newString = rx.Replace(phrase, new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator(m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant()));
```